# Algorithm - find closest two factors of an integer (minimal remainder)

Tags: algorithm

*Probably known issue, however, due to lack of knowledge and bad english, I wasn't able to query such a question properly.*

### Goal:

Given a positive integer `N`, find the non-negative integers `a,b,c` such that `N = a*b + c` where `c` is minimized. Respecting the following:

```
a <= b

(b / a) < 2

c <= (a / 2)
```

### Examples:

```
N = 24 -> a = 4, b = 6, c = 0
N = 25 -> a = 5, b = 5, c = 0
N = 26 -> a = 5, b = 5, c = 1
N = 27 -> a = 5, b = 5, c = 2
N = 28 -> a = 4, b = 7, c = 0
N = 29 -> a = 4, b = 7, c = 1
N = 30 -> a = 5, b = 6, c = 0
N = 31 -> a = 5, b = 6, c = 1
N = 32 -> a = 5, b = 6, c = 2
```

Comment: What is the question?  What are you trying to understand?

Comment: Question is: How to construct such algorithm?

Comment: How I understand the question: Given a positive integer N, find the positive integers a,b,c such that N = a*b + c where c is minimized. I suggested as an edit.

Comment: Are we assuming `a < b`?

Comment: @beaker Nearly, I think it's assumed `a <= b`

Comment: @Billiska Sure, your edit manifest my question better. Is there a known algorithm or formula?

Answer (score 1):

you don't say which language so I will do pseudocode.

```
function findFactors(num) {

    bestFactors = (0,0)
    bestRemainder = num

    for (x=num; x>0; x--) {
        for (y=num; y>0; y--) {
            if (x*y <= num) {
                if (num % (x*y) < bestRemainder) {
                    bestFactors =(x,y)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return bestFactors
}
```

admittedly with a bigO of n-squared this method is a little unruly.  There's probably a better way with recursion but I don't intend to expend that kind of brainpower right now.

Comment: thank you, please help with c# code - as I suspect implementing your pseudocode myself, will not return the wanted values (like in my examples).

Comment: I don't know c#.  You could split bestFactors var into bestFactorsX and bestFactorsY vars and then near the end:  bestFactorsX=x; bestFactorsY=y;

Comment: @user3669037 true, his code didn't check those restrictions. For stupid modification, just simply add to the `if` more conditions then.

Answer (score 0):

1. If `N` is prime return pair `((N-1) / 2, 2)`
2. Otherwise factorize `N`, `N = p1 * p2 * ... * pk, pi != 1` return `(p1, p2 * ... * pk)`

For this algorithm `c <= 1`